# Azure DevOp - Deprecated runtime (nodejs12.x) specified

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, azure-devops, aws-cloudformation

I am newer to Azure DevOps and AWS CDK (so hopefully this question makes sense). I am trying to build a pipeline and getting the following error in the step 'AWS Infra: cfn_lint':

```
E2531 Deprecated runtime (nodejs12.x) specified. Updating disabled since 2022-12-14. Please consider updating to nodejs16.x
cdk.out/prd/us-east-1/prj-name-route53-hosted-zone-stack.template.json:244:9
```

I have updated my `NODE_VERSION` in the `azure-pipeline.yaml` (which got me further in the pipeline build) but there must be somewhere else I need to update it. I am hoping someone can point me to other files I might need to update my `nodejs` version.

Answer (score 0):

> E2531 Deprecated runtime (nodejs12.x) specified. Updating disabled since 2022-12-14. Please consider updating to nodejs16.x
> cdk.out/prd/us-east-1/prj-name-route53-hosted-zone-stack.template.json:244:9

From the error message, you need to upgrade the Runtime node.js version in the prj-name-route53-hosted-zone-stack.template.json.

You can find the template.json file in your project and set the Runtime to Node.js 16.

Here is an example:

```
"Runtime": "nodejs16.x",
"Architectures": [
  "arm64"
],
"Layers": [],
"MemorySize": 256,
"Timeout": 60
```

Answer (score 0):

> I also faced the same issue, I have a runtime environment for a lambda
> as nodejs12.x. Actually this is because of end of support for Node.js
> 12.x in the AWS SDK. Reference link:  [doc link](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/announcing-the-end-of-support-for-node-js-12-x-in-the-aws-sdk-for-javascript-v3/)
>
> Solution: Update the runtime environment:
> 1.) First install nodejs updated version that you want to install e.g You can install from diff source but if you want you install with sudo
> apt-get then

```
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs@latest
```

> you can install whatever version you want to install e.g 14.x, 16.x,
> 17.x
>
> **Delete the existing package-lock.json from you package**
>
> Run below commands if needed:
>
> npm install -g nodemon@latest
>
> npm install
>
> npm ci